# Can't install TCP Activation on Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

I'm following a tutorial on WCF. In it, I get the instruction to turn on TCP Activation in the "Turn Windows features on or off" menu. See this screenshot:

[image]

However, after selecting it and pressing ok, I get this:

[image]

Googling error code 0x800F0922 yields no results, and no matter how many times I restart, I can't seem to install TCP activation. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Have you tried doing this with administrator privileges?

Comment: I always start Windows Features through the Windows button+Q menu, and I don't see how to start it with administrator privileges (right clicking it doesn't work on the menu option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by reformatting my laptop. Sadly, I could not find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you unchecked the options Framework 3.5.

Then check the options for WCF TCP then reboot the machine.
When ask you to install framework 3.5 you accept.